# Does the simulation in xcode show exactly what the real app will look like on actual devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

In xcode 7, when I run a simulation of, for example, an iphone 6, will it look exactly like it does on a real iphone 6? By this I mean will the buttons be in the same places?

I ran my app on an old iphone 4 and it looked different, but i think it might be because theres no option for siulating an iphone 4.

Answer (score 1):

You should *never* assume that you know merely from the simulator how an app will look and behave. That said, I've never known the simulator to get screen size and interface placement wrong.

Comment: Adding to this, the Simulator is just that - a *simulator*. It is constrained by the host machine's CPU and memory and is not accurate to what you'll find in the actual mobile device environment.

Comment: So, it is accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Visually yes. Everything should be identical.

However, when it comes to performance and UX, always test on a device.